# Linux Kernel Boot Error: reserving fdt memory region failed

Tags: memory, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, xilinx, u-boot

I am working on a Xilinx zcu706 board. I have developed the Linux Kernel but, when it is booting, I get an error on reserving the memory defined in device tree: *ERROR: reserving fdt memory region failed (addr=38000000 size=8000000)*

This is my device-tree, which I have copied from Xilinx tutorial:

```
/include/ "system-conf.dtsi"
/ {
    reserved-memory {
      #address-cells = <1>;
      #size-cells = <1>;
      ranges;
  
      reserved: buffer@0x38000000 {
         compatible = "shared-dma-pool";
         no-map;
         reg = <0x38000000 0x08000000>;
      };
   };
  reserved-driver@0x38000000 {
      compatible = "ingeniars,gpu4sat-memory";
      memory-region = <&reserved>;
   };
};
```

This is what happened at boot before the error:

```
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0
JTAG: Trying to boot script at 0x3000000
## Executing script at 03000000
## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at 00200000 ...
   Image Name:   Linux-5.4.0-xilinx-v2020.2
   Image Type:   ARM Linux Kernel Image (uncompressed)
   Data Size:    4325984 Bytes = 4.1 MiB
   Load Address: 00200000
   Entry Point:  00200000
   Verifying Checksum ... OK
## Loading init Ramdisk from Legacy Image at 04000000 ...
   Image Name:   petalinux-image-minimal-zynq-gen
   Image Type:   ARM Linux RAMDisk Image (uncompressed)
   Data Size:    7885622 Bytes = 7.5 MiB
   Load Address: 00000000
   Entry Point:  00000000
   Verifying Checksum ... OK
## Flattened Device Tree blob at 00100000
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0x100000
   Loading Kernel Image
   Loading Ramdisk to 1f87a000, end 1ffff336 ... OK
ERROR: reserving fdt memory region failed (addr=38000000 size=8000000)
   Loading Device Tree to 1f872000, end 1f879ce8 ... OK

Starting kernel ...
```

After the error, the boot seems to end correctly and I can use the apps that I have developed but eventually I get a Kernel Panic, that I think may be related to the error reserving memory.

Here is the kernel panic stack trace:

```
Unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at virtual address 000009b4
pgd = 330888c5
[000009b4] *pgd=00000000
Internal error: Oops - BUG: 5 [#1] PREEMPT SMP ARM
Modules linked in: krnl_gpu4sat_memory(O) krnl_gpu_sat(O) uio_pdrv_genirq
CPU: 0 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/0 Tainted: G           O      5.4.0-xilinx-v2020.2 #1
Hardware name: Xilinx Zynq Platform
PC is at update_rq_clock+0x0/0xe8
LR is at dequeue_task+0x20/0x40
pc : [<c013acfc>]    lr : [<c013ae44>]    psr: 400f0193
sp : c0b01d90  ip : 00000000  fp : c0b01da4
r10: 00000000  r9 : c0b03df4  r8 : 800f0193
r7 : ee57d104  r6 : 00000400  r5 : c0a3f180  r4 : ef7f5180
r3 : 0bea0be9  r2 : c0a3f180  r1 : ef7f5180  r0 : 00000400
Flags: nZcv  IRQs off  FIQs on  Mode SVC_32  ISA ARM  Segment none
Control: 18c5387d  Table: 2e4ec04a  DAC: 00000051
Process swapper/0 (pid: 0, stack limit = 0x23873ec4)
Stack: (0xc0b01d90 to 0xc0b02000)
1d80:                                     ee57cc80 ee57cc80 00000000 ee57d104
1da0: c0b01db4 c0140f48 ef7f5180 ee57cc80 c0b01dcc c013b74c ee57cc80 ef7f5180
1dc0: 00000000 ee57d104 c0b01dfc c013c318 ee487f20 c0b03c48 ef7f3600 ef7f3640
1de0: ef7f3600 ef7f3600 ee487f20 00000000 35cca1c4 000000a7 00000001 c016d768
1e00: ef7f3640 c016dbf0 35cca1c4 000000a7 ffffffff c016d748 c0b00000 ef7f3600
1e20: 200f0193 00000011 ffffffff 7fffffff 000000a7 000000a7 000000a7 c016e528
1e40: 200f0193 0000000f 00000003 c016e3ac 69871980 35cca1c4 000000a7 35cc9c0c
1e60: 000000a3 00000001 c0b040d4 00000011 ef015ec0 f8f01100 c0b00000 000000a7
1e80: 000000a7 c010dcfc ef008900 c015db40 00000000 00000000 ef006600 00000001
1ea0: f8f01100 c0158d90 00000000 c015933c c0b01ee0 f8f00100 c0b040cc c0b17b3c
1ec0: f8f01100 c033ec18 c052bcd0 600f0013 ffffffff c0b01f14 3768e24e c0101a8c
1ee0: 00000000 000000a7 2edb6000 ef7f5180 c0b2d5ac 00000000 ef7f4578 00000000
1f00: 3768e24e 376d9005 000000a7 000000a7 fffffff5 c0b01f30 c052bcac c052bcd0
1f20: 600f0013 ffffffff 00000051 00000000 c0b01f83 00000000 0004c5d8 00000000
1f40: ee9aef00 c0548278 00000000 ef7f4578 c0b2d5ac 00000000 c0b03c68 00000001
1f60: c0b01f80 c0b03ca8 00000000 c052bea8 ef7f4578 c0b2d5ac c0b00000 c01400ec
1f80: 017f5180 c0b03c48 00000000 000000cf 00000001 c0b36440 00000000 c0b36440
1fa0: 00000001 c0a2da40 00000000 c0140278 c0b36494 c0a00cb8 ffffffff ffffffff
1fc0: 00000000 c0a00578 00000000 c0a2da40 d337e4a0 c0b03c48 c0a00330 00000051
1fe0: 10c0387d 00000000 1f872000 413fc090 18c5387d 00000000 00000000 00000000
[<c013acfc>] (update_rq_clock) from [<c0140f48>] (update_overutilized_status.part.0+0x20/0x3c)
[<c0140f48>] (update_overutilized_status.part.0) from [<c013b74c>] (ttwu_do_activate+0x38/0x50)
Code: eaffffe4 e24bd014 e8bd88f0 c0801b38 (e59035b4)
---[ end trace 3e666a7ba6e33cb7 ]---
Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception in interrupt
CPU1: stopping
CPU: 1 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/1 Tainted: G      D    O      5.4.0-xilinx-v2020.2 #1
Hardware name: Xilinx Zynq Platform
[<c010e37c>] (unwind_backtrace) from [<c010a124>] (show_stack+0x10/0x14)
[<c010a124>] (show_stack) from [<c06a24e8>] (dump_stack+0xb4/0xd0)
[<c06a24e8>] (dump_stack) from [<c010c964>] (ipi_cpu_stop+0x3c/0x98)
[<c010c964>] (ipi_cpu_stop) from [<c010d1b0>] (handle_IPI+0x64/0x80)
[<c010d1b0>] (handle_IPI) from [<c033ec44>] (gic_handle_irq+0x84/0x90)
[<c033ec44>] (gic_handle_irq) from [<c0101a8c>] (__irq_svc+0x6c/0xa8)
Exception stack(0xef085f20 to 0xef085f68)
5f20: 00000000 000000a7 2edc5000 ef804180 c0b2d5ac 00000001 ef803578 00000000
5f40: 3ae0ed5b 4689c05e 000000a7 000000a7 fffffff5 ef085f70 c052bcac c052bcd0
5f60: 60010013 ffffffff
[<c0101a8c>] (__irq_svc) from [<c052bcd0>] (cpuidle_enter_state+0xec/0x288)
[<c052bcd0>] (cpuidle_enter_state) from [<c052bea8>] (cpuidle_enter+0x28/0x38)
[<c052bea8>] (cpuidle_enter) from [<c01400ec>] (do_idle+0x230/0x258)
[<c01400ec>] (do_idle) from [<c0140278>] (cpu_startup_entry+0x18/0x1c)
[<c0140278>] (cpu_startup_entry) from [<0010242c>] (0x10242c)
---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception in interrupt ]---
```

As I said, the kernel panic can not be traced, since it is not deterministic: it does not happened at every execution and it happened with different configurations.

Do you think the boot error can be related to the kernel panic? Do you know how can I correct the boot error?

Comment: Does the reserved memory buffer need to be at a specific physical address? If not, you can replace the `reg` property with `size` and `alignment` (and perhaps `alloc-ranges`) properties to let the kernel allocate the reserved memory dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error message is output by U-Boot before the Linux kernel ever begins execution. Note that the `Starting kernel ...` message is after this error message.

U-Boot is processing the reserved memory list to ensure that its placement of the DT blob and (optional) initramfs archive or initrd image do not conflict with those specifications. This is documented in a comment in **boot/image-fdt.c**:

```
 * Adding the memreserve regions prevents u-boot from using them to store the
 * initrd or the fdt blob.
```

---

Although it's an "error" message, this message can probably be ignored when it's from U-Boot rather than the Linux kernel. The U-Boot routine that generates this message is from **boot/image-fdt.c**:

```c
static void boot_fdt_reserve_region(struct lmb *lmb, uint64_t addr,
                    uint64_t size, enum lmb_flags flags)
{
    long ret;

    ret = lmb_reserve_flags(lmb, addr, size, flags);
    if (ret >= 0) {
        debug("   reserving fdt memory region: addr=%llx size=%llx flags=%x\n",
              (unsigned long long)addr,
              (unsigned long long)size, flags);
    } else {
        puts("ERROR: reserving fdt memory region failed ");
        printf("(addr=%llx size=%llx flags=%x)\n",
               (unsigned long long)addr,
               (unsigned long long)size, flags);
    }
}
```

Note that after trying to set the reserve flag for the memory block/region, success or failure do nothing other than display messages. Since this routine has type `void`, no return code is passed back, and the error condition is discarded by U-Boot.

---

> Do you think the boot error can be related to the kernel panic?

No, the U-Boot message is unrelated to the kernel panic.
The "error" reported by U-Boot probably indicates a conflict with the (relocated) image of U-Boot executing in high memory. (What is the address range of physical memory?) Such a (temporary) conflict should have zero effect on the Linux kernel (that has yet to begin execution).

You need to review the kernel boot log and **/proc/iomem** to verify that the designated memory region was properly reserved by the kernel.

> Do you know how can I correct the boot error?

Either ignore it, or try reserving a region lower in memory.

---

As to the cause of the kernel panic, that should be another/different post (which will require more information, e.g. the kernel version, configuration, etc.).

Comment: Thank you. Knowing that the new issues are not related surely helps.